# Can I "ignore" rain?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Am I able to stop or lessen the sound of rain, and only  rain? I want to hear all the other interesting sounds of Minecraft, but the *pitter patter* of the rain is getting to me...

Comment: You can stop the rain completely on an SMP server with /toggledownfall

Comment: does it rain a lot for you?

Comment: If you install the Too Many Items mod, you can toggle rain off any time you hear it start up.

Comment: You can replace the sound file in the minecraft.jar with a blank sound. I'll write up an answer tomorrow if there isn't one.

Comment: @MrSmooth I don't want to stop rain I just want to stop the sound.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can mute the rain sound by replacing the rain sound in the minecraft "resources" directory. No .JAR file editing required!

**Windows**:
- Navigate to %appdata%/.minecraft/resources/newsound/ambient/weather

**Mac**:
- Navigate to ~/Library/Application Support/minecraft/resources/newsound/ambient/weather

**Linux**:
- Navigate to ~/.minecraft/resources/newsound/ambient/weather

**All**:

- Download [silent.ogg](http://blog.ginzburgconsulting.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/silent.ogg) and save it to that directory (right click and save file as...)
- rename rain1, 2, 3, and 4.ogg to rain1, 2, 3 and 4.bak
- copy silent.ogg three times and rename them to rain1, 2, 3 and 4.ogg

All done! Play minecraft and now the rain will be silent.

(Note: If silent.ogg 404's on that link in the future, just search google for "silent ogg" or make one yourself in your favorite sound editor).

**Bonus**: You can do this for any sound file in the game, just browse around the resources directory for .ogg files.

Comment: Will you need to redo this every time Minecraft updates?

Comment: @OrigamiRobot I just tried it by updating Minecraft on this computer with an older copy. As expected, it did not touch the dates on the sound files, leaving my modifications intact. If an update does change the content of the rain files in the future than yes - you will need to reapply the changes. Setting the file flags to "Read Only" might work, but can't be tested unless they apply a rain-sound-changing patch.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, especially since you added the "make one yourself" part. I might make just a really quiet rain file.